# window function for moving average

Tags: pandas

I am trying to replicate SQL's window function in pandas.

```
SELECT avg(totalprice) OVER (
    PARTITION BY custkey
    ORDER BY orderdate
    RANGE BETWEEN interval '1' month PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM orders
```

I have this dataframe:

```
from io  import StringIO
import pandas as pd

myst="""cust_1,2020-10-10,100
cust_2,2020-10-10,15
cust_1,2020-10-15,200
cust_1,2020-10-16,240
cust_2,2020-12-20,25
cust_1,2020-12-25,140
cust_2,2021-01-01,5

"""
u_cols=['customer_id', 'date', 'price']

myf = StringIO(myst)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst), sep=',', names = u_cols)
df=df.sort_values(list(df.columns))
```

And after calculating moving average restricted to last 1 month, it will look like this...

```
from io  import StringIO
import pandas as pd

myst="""cust_1,2020-10-10,100,100
cust_2,2020-10-10,15,15
cust_1,2020-10-15,200,150
cust_1,2020-10-16,240,180
cust_2,2020-12-20,25,25
cust_1,2020-12-25,140,140
cust_2,2021-01-01,5,15

"""
u_cols=['customer_id', 'date', 'price', 'my_average']

myf = StringIO(myst)
import pandas as pd
my_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst), sep=',', names = u_cols)
my_df=my_df.sort_values(list(my_df.columns))
```

As shown in this image:

https://trino.io/assets/blog/window-features/running-average-range.svg

I tried to write a function like this...

```
import numpy as np
def mylogic(myro):
    mylist = list()
    mydate = myro['date'][0]
    for i in range(len(myro)):            
        if myro['date'][i] > mydate:
            mylist.append(myro['price'][i])
            mydate = myro['date'][i]
    return np.mean(mylist)
```

But that returned a key_error.

Comment: you probably need to update the data you shared; it is different from the image shared; with different outcomes

Comment: Also, see if this suffices : ``df['total_price'] = df.groupby(['customer_id', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')]).expanding(1).price.mean().array``

Comment: No. The results do not match.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, the data shared does not match the image. Also if u run the code in sql it gives a different output

Comment: mozway's answer is correct. In your case cust_2 2021-01-01 5 record is unchanged. (should be 15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) function on the last 30 days

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])    

df['my_average'] = (df.groupby('customer_id')
                      .apply(lambda d: d.rolling('30D', on='date')['price'].mean())
                      .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
                      .astype(int)
                   )
```

output:

```
  customer_id       date  price  my_average
0      cust_1 2020-10-10    100         100
2      cust_1 2020-10-15    200         150
3      cust_1 2020-10-16    240         180
5      cust_1 2020-12-25    140         140
1      cust_2 2020-10-10     15          15
4      cust_2 2020-12-20     25          25
6      cust_2 2021-01-01      5          15
```

Comment: No. This is wrong. You need to calculate average only if the date difference is less than 30 days.

Comment: Sorry, I missed this point. It should work as expected now.